# Shifting Firebase Database by one position in Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have some data in firebase database as shown below
[image]

I want to add a parent node to this data so that the whole data becomes for example  a child of a node 'Contacts'. I have searched everywhere but I haven't found any solution. The data is very huge so I don't want to delete and rewrite it. Please help

Comment: Export data as JSON file then edit and re-import, Job Done :)

Comment: I cant believe it's this simple. Thanks Charitha